# Haskell: my program doesn't make conversion

Tags: haskell

I have made a simple program that deals with queue data structure that I have implemented. Here is my code

```
transf :: Queue -> [Char]
transf emptyQueue = []  
transf queue = [front queue] ++ transf (dequeue queue)
```

where Queue is

```
newtype Queue = Q [Char] deriving (Show)

emptyQueue :: Queue
emptyQueue = Q []

queueIsEmpty :: Queue -> Bool
queueIsEmpty (Q []) = True
queueIsEmpty (Q _) = False

enqueue :: Char -> Queue -> Queue
enqueue x (Q q) = Q (q ++ [x])

dequeue :: Queue -> Queue
dequeue (Q (_:xs)) = Q xs
dequeue (Q []) = error "dequeue: empty queue"

front :: Queue -> Char
front (Q (x:_)) = x
front (Q []) = error "front: empty queue"
```

My program doesn't convert queue into string. Where is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also check out this interesting and elegant way to improve runtime performance by using two lists instead of one: http://fateswanderer.wordpress.com/2012/07/22/functional-data-structures-notes/

Comment: thanks, it helped me to improve my understanding on data structures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
transf emptyQueue = []
```

Here `emptyQueue` is simply the name of your parameter. You are not pattern matching against the contents of the global `emptyQueue`. You can't pattern match against variables like that - only against constructors.

You have to write `transf (Q [])` to match the empty queue, but note that your whole function could simply be defined as `transf (Q xs) = xs`.